# PHP Scope Resolution Operator: This code is showing a lot of errors due to 10th line of code

Tags: php

I am very new to object oriented PHP.
I just wrote a code to practice, but its showing errors such as

```
Notice: Undefined variable: type in F:\xampp\htdocs\testing\scope.php on line 10
Notice: Undefined index: in F:\xampp\htdocs\testing\scope.php on line 10
```

I think its because of `$type` that this error is coming. Can someone please help? Thanks in advance.

```
class Lookup {
    public static $items = array();
    public $x = '34';
    public $y = '26';

    public static function setItems($items, $x, $y) {
        $items[$type] = array(
                'x' => $this->x,
                'y' => $this->y);
    }

    public static function getSum() {
        $z = self::$items[$type]['x'] + self::$items[$type]['y'];
        return $z;
    }
}

echo Lookup::getSum();
```

Comment: Where does `$type` come from? This isn't an OOP issue.

Comment: Which PHP version are you using? [*Late Static Bindings*](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) where introduced in 5.3

Comment: It's not an OOP issue as George said. The `$type` variable simply doesn't exist here in the code!

Comment: And you cannot access `$this` in your static function (that would be your next question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of inconsistencies in your code, which I'll run through:

`setItems()`

- There are 2 parameters, `$x` and `$y`, which are never used.
- The method body references a variable `$type` which is undefined.
- The method uses the `$this` keyword, which isn't available inside a static method (they have no object context).

`getSum()`

- As you've already found out , `$type` doesn't exist. Did you mean to pass it in as a parameter?

Even though the undefined variable issue isn't directly related to OOP, I can tell that you don't quite understand the paradigm. Have a look at the PHP docs on [`Classes and Objects`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

Answer (score 2):

> Declaring class properties or methods as static makes them accessible
>   without needing an instantiation of the class. A property declared as
>   static can not be accessed with an instantiated class object (though a
>   static method can).
>
> For compatibility with PHP 4, if no visibility declaration is used,
>   then the property or method will be treated as if it was declared as
>   public.
>
> Because static methods are callable without an instance of the object
>   created, the pseudo-variable $this is not available inside the method
>   declared as static.
>     *[from php.org](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)*

One solution for it is to turn everything into static (this way you can call `Lookup::getSum()` without an instantiation of the class):

```
class Lookup{
  public static $items = array();
  public static $x = '11114';
  public static $y = '26';
  public static function setItems(){
    self::$items = array('x'=>self::$x ,'y'=>self::$y);
  }
  public static function getSum(){

    $z = self::$items['x'] + self::$items['y'];
    return $z;
  }
}
echo  Lookup::setItems();
echo  Lookup::getSum();
```

The reason why your way didn't work is because within class methods, only non-static properties can be accessed by `->`
 (Object Operator):

> $this->property (where property is the name of the
>    property).

Static properties can only be accessed by using the :: (Double
 Colon):

> self::$property

and thus in your codes you should access the variables this way (not suggested though, as it is a really bad OO Design)

```
class Lookup{
  public static $items = array();
  public $x = '11114';
  public $y = '26';

  public function setItems(){
    self::$items = array('x'=>$this->x ,'y'=>$this->y);
  }

  public static function getSum(){
    $z = self::$items['x'] + self::$items['y'];
    return $z;
  }

}

$a = new Lookup();
$a->setItems();

echo Lookup::getSum();
//11140
```

Comment: Think about how your first example actually flows. It's a **terrible** solution.

Comment: @GeorgeBrighton I just want to demonstrate to OP that you need `self::` for static variable and `$this->` for non-static variable.

Comment: Mind removing the down-votes? Else I'd rather have this answer not accepted so I can delete it.

Comment: It's there because of your first example. Having to instantiating a class and call a method to set it up so you can call one of its static methods (using an object!) is horrible design.

Comment: @GeorgeBrighton I was just trying to help OP by demonstrating to him how he can access to the variables in his original codes.